# Maven and Tycho code signing on OS X

Tags: eclipse, maven, rcp, codesign, tycho

I am trying to code sign my Eclipse RCP application using a Maven+Tycho build system.

I added this piece of code to my pom.xml in order to sign the .app that gets created on the OS X box:

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.1</version>
                    <executions>
                      <execution>
                <id>exec</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                          <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                      </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                      <executable>codesign</executable>
                      <workingDirectory>/tmp</workingDirectory>
                      <arguments>
                        <argument>-s</argument>
                        <argument>"My Developer ID"</argument>
                        <argument>-vvv</argument>
                        <argument>${project.build.directory}/products/${product-id}/macosx/cocoa/x86/MyApp/MyApp.app"</argument>
                      </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                  </plugin>
```

But it keeps giving me this error:

**"My Developer ID": no identity found**

I read about unlocking the keychain but it really had no effect on my build. And yes, I'm running the build as mvn clean install from the same account owning that certificate.

Is there anyone who managed to solve this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Tried removing the quotes around your developer id?

Comment: Run your build with the '-X' argument and you should see the exact command which gets executed. Then run it in the CLI to see what the problem is.

Comment: @MartinEllis removing the double quotes did the trick.

Comment: @RobertMunteanu The weird thing is that with the double quotes and the -X it shown the command line that I run by hand to codesign the app. But removing them did the trick anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Martin Ellis, removing the double quotes around my developer ID did the trick.